# nodejs https request throws error when using Content-Type

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

The following code is with the Dropbox API, it worked during testing but when I added the "Content-Type":"application/json" in the parameters it broke.

```
https.request(options, function(resp){
        let creds = [];
        let ts = "";
        resp.on('data', function(body){
            creds.push(body);
            let jsonarray = Array.prototype.slice.call(creds, 0).toString().split(",");
            let token = "Bearer " + jsonarray[0].substring(jsonarray[0].indexOf(':') + 3, jsonarray[0].length - 1);
            ts = token;
        });
        resp.on('end', function(){
            let connectfilelist = {
                hostname: 'api.dropboxapi.com',
                path: '/2/files/list_folder',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {Authorization: ts,
                "Content-Type", "application/json"}
            };

            https.request(connectfilelist, function(resp){
                let flist = [];
                resp.on('data', function(chunk){
                    flist.push(chunk.toString());
                });
                resp.on('end', function(){
                    console.log(flist);
                    res.render('mydropbox', flist);
                });
            }).end(bodyParams);
        });
    }).end(bodyParams);
```

This is the error I get when i omit that parameter:

```
[ 'Error in call to API function "files/list_folder": This function requires its argument in the HTTP request body, but your request body is empty.' ]
```

When I include the Content-Type, it throws this:

```
[ 'Error in call to API function "files/list_folder": request body: could not decode input as JSON' ]
```

I think that the way I am stating the parameters might be in a string and not JSON format, but I am not sure where I would change something.

Comment: I assume you want to fetch folders list. If you ask for that using list_folder you should use 'GET' instead of 'POST'. Otherwise you need to provide data that you want to send to that endpoint.

Comment: I have tried using GET and an error returns saying it will only accept POST

Comment: [ 'Error in call to API function "files/list_folder": Your request\'s HTTP request method is "GET".  This function only accepts the HTTP request method "POST".' ]

Comment: So according to the docs, you need to send which folder you want to list. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder describe body of the POST request.

Comment: Look at the Example box there and --data parameter.

Comment: I added that and it did not work. Is there a possibility it isn't converting to JSON? I keep getting "could not decode input as JSON" if I have the Content-Type parameter set to application/json, regardless of the other parameters.